# Assert boolean response with restassured SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, rest-assured

I want to evaluate Boolean response coming from my Rest Controller in Spring Boot Junit Test Case. The response seems to be the same but Rest Assured is putting brackets in the response value.

My Controller:-

```
@PutMapping("/file/{id}")
ResponseEntity<Boolean> uploadFile(@RequestBody MultipartFile file,
        @PathVariable String id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                fileService.uploadImage(file, id),
                HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

My Test Case:-

```
@Test
    public void UploadAttachmentTest() throws Exception {
        given().pathParam("id", "randomId").multiPart(dummyFile).expect()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED).body(equalTo(true)).when()
                .put("/file/{id}");
    }
```

Error while running junit test case:-

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Response body doesn't match expectation.
Expected: <true>
  Actual: true

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:237)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:249)
....
```

Comment: What is the response body?. Response body should be in json format. So you should compare the particular value from the json body with the expected result.

Comment: As you see in the controller Return type, I am expecting a boolean value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `is` instead of `equal`:

```java
  .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED).body(is(true)).when()
```

Answer (score 0):

extract the response as in the format you want exactly.something looks like below snippet.

```
    @Test
    public void UploadAttachmentTest() throws Exception {
        Boolean response = given()
                          .pathParam("id", "randomId")
                          .multiPart(dummyFile)
                          .expect()
                          .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED)
                          .extract().response().as(Boolean.class);

        // Here u can check response with assertTrue() or assertFalase()
        assertTrue(response);
    }
```